# Visual Studio Post-build event exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Here's the command from Visual Studio project properties (Post-build, runs on successful build):

```
copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)Library\Gecko\XulRunner\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
```

This exits with Code 1. Here's the command from the Output window:

```
copy /Y "C:\Workspace\MyProject\Library\Gecko\XulRunner\*.*" "C:\Workspace\MyProject\bin\Debug\"
```

When I paste that command on the command line, it works properly with no error message. Most of the same issues I've found were caused by not surrounding the paths with quotes, or by trying to copy over read-only files. However, since the command does run successfully in the command line I'm not really sure how to debug this. Is there a way I can get more details about the failure?

Comment: Do you really need the `*.*` after the $(TargetDir)? I have something like your command but I have no `*.*`

Comment: It appears that I do not need it, so I removed it. However, the original problem still exists.

Comment: If you don't see an error message in the Output window then there's little to guess at.  Do favor XCOPY, it fails in a more diagnosable way and, above all, avoids making needless copies with /D

Comment: Is it possible that some file to be overwritten is locked in the TargetDir?. Just for test you could try to copy in a subfolder of the TargetDir.

Comment: @HansPassant, It appears using XCopy with the /D switch was the solution. Visual Studio was locking certain .dlls and wouldn't let me replace them. If you post as answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for the idea. That helped me find the solution. It appears Visual Studio was locking the files and now allowing me to replace them.

Answer (score -1):

your dll can be used other place or your project can be running.

Comment: Can you provide some further detail? As it stands your answer is more of a comment

Comment: i think its very clear. if you try to build project, while the project is working, it will cause the error or your dll is used somewhere its will also cause error